# Move data from an on-premise SQL server to SQL Azure with Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, sql-server-2012-web

Scenario:

I need to:

1) Run a job on my sql server(Source) through Azure Data Factory.

2) Maintain consistency across Sql Server 2012 (Web Edition) and SQL Azure for 7 of my tables

Current Approach: I was opting to use azure data factory, but need to know the complete flow for my scenario.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would start with this article [Move data from an on-premise SQL server to SQL Azure with Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-data-science-move-sql-azure-adf).  Otherwise this question is a bit broad and will probably get closed.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a SO question as a result of an error. It sounds like you need an architect to come and design the solution for you!

Comment: Hey can you guide me to invoke stored procedure using "author and deploy" in  azure data factory in my sql server 2012 web edition , copy the data from the aggregation and update it to sql azure.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install and configure Data Management Gateway, then create the linked service for your SQL Server 2012, for more details, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-move-data-between-onprem-and-cloud .

Also you would need to create the linked service for Azure Blob Storage and Azure SQL database, for detailed steps, please review this similar blog:http://www.tenpoint7.com/2016/02/how-to-setup-azure-data-factory-adf/.

Comment: Hey! I have already done that, need help in writing the json part for 



Exec SP onPremise -> Copy to Storage -> Exec SP Azure SQL -> Copy to Azure SQl

Comment: The steps that create JSON files and create pipeline are well introduced in this official article:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-data-science-move-sql-azure-adf, what issues do you get in the process?

Comment: The problem faced is in executing the stored procedure at source and sink, i cannot figure out how to provide credentials for stored procedure

Thanks